# Ghost on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, ghost

I'm trying to host a Ghost blog alongside a Node app I already have running on Heroku, it's working on my local setup but doesn't load on production (Heroku). I feel like it's something small I'm missing so all help is appreciated:

Here is the tutorial I'm following: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Using-Ghost-as-an-NPM-module

server.js

```
"use strict";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const parentApp = express();
const path = require('path');
var ghost = require('ghost');

ghost({
  config: path.join(__dirname, 'ghost/config.js')
}).then(function (ghostServer) {
    parentApp.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);

    ghostServer.start(parentApp);
});
```

config.js

````
// # Ghost Configuration
// Setup your Ghost install for various [environments](http://support.ghost.org/config/#about-environments).

// Ghost runs in `development` mode by default. Full documentation can be found at http://support.ghost.org/config/

var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {
    // ### Production
    // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment.
    // Configure your URL and mail settings here
    production: {
        url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'postgres',
            connection: {
                host: 'host',
                user: 'user',
                password: 'password',
                database: 'database',
                port: 5432
            }
        },

        server: {
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: process.env.PORT
        },
        paths: {
            contentPath: path.join(__dirname, '/ghost/content')
        }
    },

    // ### Development **(default)**
    development: {
        // The url to use when providing links to the site, E.g. in RSS and email.
        // Change this to your Ghost blog's published URL.
        url: 'http://localhost:2368/blog/',

        // Example refferer policy
        // Visit https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/ for instructions
        // default 'origin-when-cross-origin',
        // referrerPolicy: 'origin-when-cross-origin',

        // Example mail config
        // Visit http://support.ghost.org/mail for instructions
        // ```
        //  mail: {
        //      transport: 'SMTP',
        //      options: {
        //          service: 'Mailgun',
        //          auth: {
        //              user: '', // mailgun username
        //              pass: ''  // mailgun password
        //          }
        //      }
        //  },
        // ```

        // #### Database
        // Ghost supports sqlite3 (default), MySQL & PostgreSQL
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        // #### Server
        // Can be host & port (default), or socket
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '2368'
        },
        // #### Paths
        // Specify where your content directory lives
        paths: {
            contentPath: path.join(__dirname, '/content/')
        }
    },

    // **Developers only need to edit below here**

    // ### Testing
    // Used when developing Ghost to run tests and check the health of Ghost
    // Uses a different port number
    testing: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-test.db')
            },
            pool: {
                afterCreate: function (conn, done) {
                    conn.run('PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;' +
                    'PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;' +
                    'PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;' +
                    'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE; COMMIT;', done);
                }
            },
            useNullAsDefault: true
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        },
        logging: false
    },

    // ### Testing MySQL
    // Used by Travis - Automated testing run through GitHub
    'testing-mysql': {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'mysql',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'root',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_testing',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        },
        logging: false
    },

    // ### Testing pg
    // Used by Travis - Automated testing run through GitHub
    'testing-pg': {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'pg',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'postgres',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_testing',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        },
        logging: false
    }
};

module.exports = config;
````

When I try to access the address I listed on config.js I get

> Cannot GET /blog/

Any idea on what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: have you added Procfile ?

Comment: @ricky what for? My application is already up and running, I just can't get Ghost to work

Comment: You ever figure this out? I am having the same issue on appengine

Comment: @AlexanderN. no :( Ended up using Jekyll